# HTML5 Image Upload to Page Polyfill Demo

Tags: html, file-upload

I'm building a file upload using HTML5 - it's only being uploaded to the page, which is what I want.

https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader This is what I've found and I would like some help how to implement this. There are no demos that I can find so I'm not even sure it's what I want, there are many out there and I've been doing a lot of research.

Here is what I've got http://jsfiddle.net/tara_irvine/CR3Q8/2/ I need to add a fallback for Safari and IE.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction? If this polyfill will work can someone explain how I implement it?

Thanks very much, I realize this could be a repeat of a question that already exists but the only answers I've found are for uploading to the server. I only want the image to be displayed on the page, eventually I will want to export it, initial thoughts are HTML5 div > canvas and export as image or something... I'll need to have a fallback for this too. but first things first! Getting the image into the page.

Thanks for any help I recieve